# Vector of templated vectors

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I want to create a vector of vectors, where the individual vectors can be of different types, as follows:

```
std::vector<int> v1;
std::vector<float> v2;
std::vector<double> v3;

std::vector<SomeType> all;
all.push_back(v1);
all.push_back(v2);
all.push_back(v3);
```

What should `SomeType` be in this case?

My actual use case:

I have vectors of different data types which need to be written out to disk. Everytime I add a column to the dataset, I don't want to have to specify the column in various different places. I want to be able to iterate through the columns easily.

Comment: [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)? But I'm really curious about the *real* problem you need to solve? *Why* do you think you need such a vector?

Comment: How would you know to go back from `all[1]` to `std::vector<float>`?

Comment: Refrain. That's not the way the language is built from ground. My advice if to find a different design allowing more idiomatic C++ code. It is certainly possible but will be hard to use and maintain.

Comment: Does "add a column to the dataset" happen at compile time, or at runtime? It sounds like you are describing `struct Row { int a; float x; double price; }; std::vector<Row> all;`

Comment: Yes that is what I had. But in writing out the values, I have separate vectors that need to take the individual values of the struct. Ideally I could iterate over the struct members.

Comment: I would recommend posting the actual problem you are trying to solve as a separate question. It is possible there are other, more elegant solutions, that do not involve vectors of different types.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of ways to do this, depending on your situation. Here's a variant (pun) with std::variant:

```
std::vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
std::vector<float> v2 = { 4.5f, 5.5f, 6.5f };
std::vector<double> v3 = { 7.5, 8.5, 9.5 };

std::vector<std::variant<std::vector<int>, std::vector<float>, std::vector<double>>> all;
all.push_back(v1);
all.push_back(v2);
all.push_back(v3);

for(auto& variant : all)
{
    std::visit([](const auto& container) {
        for(auto value : container)
        {
            std::cout << value << '\n';
        }
    }, variant);
}
```

`std::any` with type erasure would also work. Or go one level lower, f.i. with `std::vector<std::variant<int, float, double>>`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without specifying the container type of `all` manually?

Comment: You can typedef the inner variant: using MyVariant = std::variant< ... >;, and use auto where the type can be inferred. But you have to state it at least once :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this because all 3 vector types are different.

You can however, create a non-templated abstract class with the required abstract functions that you need for std::vector then implement it for each vector type.

Something like this:

```
struct Base
{
      int size() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct VectorWrapper : public Base
{
      std::vector<T>* mVector;
      int size() { return mVector.size(); }
};

int main()
{
     std::vector<int> v;
     // initialize vector

     VectorWrapper<int> w;
     w.mVector = &v;

     std::vector<Base*> all;
     all.push_back(&w)

     return 0; 
}
```

Comment: But then if I want to iterate through the vector all, how do I access the underlying mVector without casting to VectorWrapper? In which case I need to know the type which means I can't loop through it?

Comment: Yes, you have to cast. dynamic_cast returns nullptr when the types don't match though so if there's only a few types you expect, you can deal with each case with a dynamic cast and a check that you didn't get nullptr back. But by that point It's probably worth finding a way to do what you're doing without this vector of vectors

Comment: @user3055163 That's why the whole concept is pretty much flawed. You can only loop through something if you know the type, and there is no easy way to _get_ that type once you create `std::vector<SomeType>`. `std::variant` with `std::visit` might help you, or other forms of rigorous templating (if you have a compile-time mapping from column index to type).